# Measure similarity of objects over a period of time

Tags: math, data-science, data-analysis, similarity

I've got a dataset that has monthly metrics for different stores. Each store has three monthly (Total sales, customers and transaction count), my task is over a year I need to find the store that most closely matches a specific test store (Ex: Store 77).

Therefore over the year both the test store and most similar store need to have similar performance. My question is how do I go about finding the most similar store? I've currently used euclidean distance but would like to know if there's a better way to go about it.

Thanks in advance

| STORE | month | Metric 1 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 22 | Jan-18 | 10 |
| 23 | Jan-18 | 20 |

Is correlation a better way to measure similarity in this case compared to distance? I'm fairly new to data so if there's any resources where I can learn more about this stuff it would be much appreciated!!

Answer (score 0):

In general, deciding *similarity* of items is *domain-specific*, i.e. it depends on the problem you try to solve. Therefore, there is not one-size-fits-all solution. Nevertheless, there is some a basic procedure someone can follow trying to solve this kind of problems.

### Case 1 - only distance matters:

If you want to find the most similar items (*stores* in our case) using a **distance** measure, it's a good tactic to firstly **scale** your features in some way.

##### Example (min-max normalization):

| Store | Month | Total sales | Total sales (normalized) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Jan-18 | 50 | 0.64 |
| 2 | Jan-18 | 40 | 0.45 |
| 3 | Jan-18 | 70 | 0 |
| 4 | Jan-18 | 15 | 1 |

After you apply normalization on all attributes, you can calculate euclidean distance or any other metric that you think it fits your data.

###### Some resources:

- [Similarity measures](https://towardsdatascience.com/17-types-of-similarity-and-dissimilarity-measures-used-in-data-science-3eb914d2681)
- [Feature scaling](https://towardsdatascience.com/all-about-feature-scaling-bcc0ad75cb35)

### Case 2 - Trend matters:

Now, say that you want to find the similarity over the **whole year**. If the *definition* of similarity for your problem is just the **instance** of the stores at the end of the year, then distance will do the job.

But if you want to find similar *trends* of *increase/decrease* of the attributes of two stores, then **distance** measures conceal this information. You would have to use **correlation** metrics or any other more sophisticated technique than just a distance.

##### Simple example:

To keep it simple, let's say we are interested in 3-months analysis and that we use only sales attribute (unscaled):

| Store | Month | Total sales |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Jan-18 | 20 |
| 1 | Feb-18 | 20 |
| 1 | Mar-18 | 20 |
| 2 | Jan-18 | 5 |
| 2 | Feb-18 | 15 |
| 2 | Mar-18 | 40 |
| 3 | Jan-18 | 10 |
| 3 | Feb-18 | 30 |
| 3 | Mar-18 | 78 |

At the end of March, in terms of **distance** `Store 1` and `Store 2` are *identical*, both having `60 total sales`.

But, as far as the **increase ratio per month** is concerned, `Store 2` and `Store 3` is our match. In *February* they both had `2 times more sales` and in March `1.67 and 1.6 times more sales` respectively.

**Bottom line:** *It really depends on what you want to quantify.*

###### Well-known correlation metrics:

- [Pearson correlation coefficient](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.pearsonr.html)
- [Spearman correlation coefficient](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.spearmanr.html)